# Html no lee función javascript

Tags: javascript, html, fetch

Buenas noches: tengo que llenar un select actualizable dinamicamente por medio de javascript, éste es el código:

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 mb-3">
   <label class="etiqueta_formulario" for="ramo_nueva_empresa">Ramo Empresa</label>
   <select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="ramo_nueva_empresa" id="ramo_nueva_empresa" style="cursor:pointer" required>
      <option selected value="0">Seleccione ...</option>
         <script type="text/javascript">
            cargaDatosGenerales('ramoEmpresas');
         </script>
   </select>
   <div class="invalid-feedback" style="width: 100%;">
      Seleccione el ramo de la Empresa.
   </div>
</div>
```

La función cargaDatosGenerales() se encuentra en el archivo functions.js que es cargado desde el principio. El problema que se me presenta es que el documento no lee y, por lo tanto, no carga la función.

```
function cargaDatosGenerales(tarea) {
   console.log('Aquí estoy '+window.location);

   let ruta = "../main/transData.php";

   fetch(ruta)
      .then( response => {
         return response.text()
      })
      .then(data => {
          AQUÍ COLOCARÉ EL SCRIPT PARA LLENAR EL SELECT
      });
}
```

Ya intenté colocando la función en el encabezado del documento y tampoco la lee, le cambié el nombre a la función en el archivo functions.js, para probar si la leía pero ni siquiera me da error, por último coloqué un console.log con un texto en el mismo select y tampoco lo imprime en la consola. Ya he utilizado éste método en otros sistemas y me ha funcionado, no entiendo que puede estar pasando.

Comment: Si te imprime el `console.log('Aquí estoy '+window.location);` ??

Comment: Nada, tampoco la imprime

Comment: El script no puede ser parte del select, prueba poniéndolo debajo del div.

Comment: Triby, si lo coloco debajo del div me va a pintar los datos fuera del select. Como ya aclaré al final de mi pregunta, es un procedimiento que he utilizado en todos mis proyectos cuando se trata de selects actualizables de forma dinámica y me funciona bien. No entiendo que puede estar pasando ésta vez, por eso posteé la pregunta.

Comment: Honestamente nunca había visto llamar un método de un script dentro de un script, pero yo en el trabajo lo hago desde el header, agrego el script y con `src` le indico donde se encuentra mi archivo javascripr`<header> <script src="../my/path/to/file.js" type="text/javascript"></script> </header>` este se ejecuta al cargar la página, por lo que en tu .js tenes que llamar al método

Comment: Tú hablas de llamar un archivo .js y ése no es mi caso, yo estoy llamando a una función dentro de un html, eso es totalmente normal.
Lo que se hace es colocar todos los scripts (JavaScript o JQuery) en un sólo archivo con extensión .js, cargarlo al principio del sistema e ir accediendo a cada función dentro de ése archivo .js cuando se necesite.

Comment: Es justo lo que hace lo que te digo... Sii quieres acceder a un método del archivo .js desde alguna etiqueta, usas los triggers tipo onload, onclick y así... i.e. `<div onclick="cargaDatosGenerales("Hola!")"></div>`

Comment: Eso se hace en caso de que tenga que hacer click, etc en un elemento, en mi caso quiero que haga la consulta cuando cargue el DOM, traiga los datos y llene el select respectivo. No es un procedimiento loco, ni mal planteado, ni inventado, como te dije lo hago todo el timepo y me funciona a la perfección.

Comment: Te explico algo: ese select forma parte de un formulario que llena el cliente cuando quiere ingresar una nueva empresa.
Si al abrir el select no aparece el ramo de la empresa que quiere registrar no voy a decirle que salga del formulario y pierda los demás datos que ya ha ingresado para ir al módulo de mantenimiento e ingresar el nuevo ramo para luego volver a llenar el formulario.

Comment: Lo lógico es que le des la oportunidad, desde el mismo formulario, que haga click en otro botón y dentro de un modal agregue el nuevo ramo y al guardarse actualice ese select, le aparezca el nuevo item y continúe llenando el formulario. ¿Tienes alguna forma de hacerlo, en tiempo de ejecución, distinta a como lo estoy planteando?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que he encontrado cual es el problema, cuya solución es simple.
El problema está en que el html con el elemento `<script>` se está cargando antes que el javascript por lo que parece, y por eso no se encuentra la función.

La solución simple es encerrarlo dentro de una función que espere la carga del DOM antes de ejecutarse, como por ejemplo [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload):

```javascript
window.onload = function() {
    cargaDatosGenerales('ramoEmpresas');
}
```

Aquí dejo un snippet con todo funcionando:

```js
function cargaDatosGenerales(tarea) {
  console.log('Aquí estoy ' + window.location);

  let ruta = "../main/transData.php";

  fetch(ruta)
    .then(response => {
      return response.text()
    })
    .then(data => {
      // AQUÍ COLOCARÉ EL SCRIPT PARA LLENAR EL SELECT
    });
}
```

```html
<div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 mb-3">
  <label class="etiqueta_formulario" for="ramo_nueva_empresa">Ramo Empresa</label>
  <select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="ramo_nueva_empresa" id="ramo_nueva_empresa" style="cursor:pointer" required>
    <option selected value="0">Seleccione ...</option>
    <script>
      window.onload = function() {
        cargaDatosGenerales('ramoEmpresas');
      }
    </script>
  </select>
  <div class="invalid-feedback" style="width: 100%;">
    Seleccione el ramo de la Empresa.
  </div>
</div>
```